# Extract string from a large string oracle regexp

Tags: regex, oracle

I have String as below.

```
select b.col1,a.col2,lower(a.col3) from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.col = b.col and a.col = b.col
inner join (select col1, col2, col3,col4 from tablename ) c on a.col1=b.col2    
where
a.col = 'value'
```

Output need to be `table1,table2` and tablename from above string. please let me know the regex to get the result.

Comment: Where this string comes from? What is the context? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I did tried,with t as
(SELECT 'select fro_date,date_frm,col3 from emp,sampletable(select deptno,dname from dept where dname=mn) where deptno=10' a FROM DUAL),
trans as
(select REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(replace(TRANSLATE(UPPER(a),CHR(10)||CHR(11)||CHR(13),' '),'FROM','FROM #'),'WHERE','# WHERE'),'SELECT(.*?)FROM+','FROM') TRANS from t)
select 
case when trans like '%WHERE%' then REGEXP_SUBSTR(trans, '(#)(.*)(*#+)')  
     when trans like '%FROM%' and trans not like '%WHERE%' then REGEXP_SUBSTR(trans, '(#)(.*)')  end REGEXP_SUBSTR
from trans res # EMP,SAMPLETABLE(FROM # DEPT # WHERE DNAME=MN) #

Answer (score 0):

Should be a simple one :-)

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  select q'[select b.col1,a.col2,lower(a.col3) from table1 a inner join table2 b on
  3  a.col = b.col and a.col = b.col inner join (select col1, col2, col3,col4 from tablename )
  4  c on a.col1=b.col2 where a.col = 'value']' str
  5  FROM DUAL)
  6  SELECT LISTAGG(TABLE_NAMES, ' , ') WITHIN GROUP (
  7  ORDER BY val) table_names
  8  FROM
  9    (SELECT 1 val,
 10      regexp_substr(str,'table[[:alnum:]]+',1,level) table_names
 11    FROM DATA
 12      CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(str,'table')
 13    )
 14  /

TABLE_NAMES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
table1 , table2 , tablename

SQL>
```

**Brief explanation, so that OP/even others might find it useful :**

- The `REGEXP_SUBSTR` looks for the words 'table', it could be followed
  by a number or string like 1,2, name etc.
- To find all such words, I used `connect by level` technique, but it
  gives the output in different rows.
- Finally, to put them in a single row as comma separated values, I
  used `LISTAGG`.
- Oh yes, and that q'[]' is the string literal technique.

Comment: `REGEXP` not _CPU intensive_? 8-)

Comment: I knew that comment would come, lol. Well, it seems to be a one time activity by the nature of the requirement. It can't be a BATCH process or OLTP ;-)

Comment: Lalit Thanks for the solution. In this case table is constant in table1,table2 and tablename. If table name varies like emp, dept and salgrade in that case 'table[[:alnum:]]+' might not match right. I tried with regexp_replace, still i am unable to get the desider output for eg: with t as
(SELECT 'select from_date,date_from,col3 from emp,(select deptno,dname from dept where dname=mn) where deptno=10' a FROM DUAL)
select regexp_replace(a,'(select(.*?)from)','#') from t is resulting in #_date,date_from,col3 from emp,(# dept where dname=mn) where deptno=10 instead of emp, dept

Comment: In that case, you need to extract the word immediately following the FROM keyword.I will leave that up to you to learn. Hope the answer helped, and you understood my explanation.